# set proxy for webdriver manager

Tags: angular, testing, web-applications, protractor

I have installed protractor by using `npm install -g protractor` then I am trying to update `webdriver-manager update` but it is giving an error for chrome driver googleapis and same for selenium. Please tell me how to set a proxy with full command, what username password should be given?

Comment: could you post error log

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to pass proxy with `--proxy="@username:password<proxy>:port"` as an argument.
if still not working add --ignore_ssl.